# Save cropped image in different width and height

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am using [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to crop images.

**This is the form that i upload the image and crop.**

```
                <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
                <!-- hidden crop params -->
                <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
                <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
                <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
                <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />

                <div><input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" /></div>

                <div class="error"></div>

                <div class="step2">
                    <h2>Step2: Please select a crop region</h2>
                    <img id="preview" />

                    <div class="info">
                        <label>File size</label> <input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" />
                        <label>Type</label> <input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" />
                        <label>Image dimension</label> <input type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
                        <label>W</label> <input type="text" id="w" name="w" />
                        <label>H</label> <input type="text" id="h" name="h" />
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

**upload.php file which upload cropped image to *avatar* directory.**

```
<?php function uploadImageFile() { // Note: GD library is required for this function

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $iWidth = $iHeight = 200; // desired image result dimensions
    $iJpgQuality = 90;

    if ($_FILES) {

        // if no errors and size less than 250kb
        if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) {

                // new unique filename
                $sTempFileName = 'avatar/' . md5(time().rand());

                // move uploaded file into cache folder
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);

                // change file permission to 644
                @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

                if (file_exists($sTempFileName) && filesize($sTempFileName) > 0) {
                    $aSize = getimagesize($sTempFileName); // try to obtain image info
                    if (!$aSize) {
                        @unlink($sTempFileName);
                        return;
                    }

                    // check for image type
                    switch($aSize[2]) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $sExt = '.jpg';

                            // create a new image from file 
                            $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($sTempFileName);
                            break;
                        /*case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $sExt = '.gif';

                            // create a new image from file 
                            $vImg = @imagecreatefromgif($sTempFileName);
                            break;*/
                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $sExt = '.png';

                            // create a new image from file 
                            $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($sTempFileName);
                            break;
                        default:
                            @unlink($sTempFileName);
                            return;
                    }

                    // create a new true color image
                    $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

                    // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
                    imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);

                    // define a result image filename
                    $sResultFileName = $sTempFileName . $sExt;

                    // output image to file
                    imagejpeg($vDstImg, $sResultFileName, $iJpgQuality);
                    @unlink($sTempFileName);

                    return $sResultFileName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

  $sImage = uploadImageFile();
  echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
  ?>
```

**My Question:**

Right now it just upload the cropped image in ***avatar*** directory with width and height of 200px.

I want to also upload that cropped image in to two other directories

1. ***avatar1*** with width and height of 500px
2. ***avatar2*** with width and height of 700px

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add arguments to your function, e.g. `uploadImageFile($dirName, $iWidth, $iHeight)` and then invoke it multiple times with different sizes

```
<?php 
    function uploadImageFile() { // Note: GD library is required for this function

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $iJpgQuality = 90;

        if ($_FILES) {
            // if no errors and size less than 250kb
            if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024) {
                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) {
                    if (!is_dir('avatar')) {
                        mkdir('avatar');
                    }
                    // new unique filename
                    $sTempFileName = 'avatar/' . md5(time().rand());
                    // move uploaded file into cache folder
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);

                    // change file permission to 644
                    @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

                    $sResultFileName = copyImageFile('avatar', $sTempFileName, 200, 200, $iJpgQuality);
                    if ($sResultFileName) {
                        copyImageFile('avatar1', $sTempFileName, 500, 500);
                        copyImageFile('avatar2', $sTempFileName, 700, 700);
                        @unlink($sTempFileName);

                        return $sResultFileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function copyImageFile($dirName, $originImageName, $iWidth, $iHeight, $iJpgQuality = 90) {
    if (file_exists($originImageName) && filesize($originImageName) > 0) {        
        $aSize = getimagesize($originImageName); // try to obtain image info
        if (!$aSize) {
            @unlink($originImageName);
            return;
        }

        // check for image type
        switch($aSize[2]) {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $sExt = '.jpg';
                $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($originImageName);
                break;
            /*case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $sExt = '.gif';

                // create a new image from file 
                $vImg = @imagecreatefromgif($sTempFileName);
                break;*/
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $sExt = '.png';
                $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($originImageName);
                break;
            default:
                @unlink($originImageName);
                return;
        }

        // create a new true color image
        $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

        // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);

        // define a result image filename        
        if (!is_dir($dirName)) {
            mkdir($dirName);
        }
        $newImageName = $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(time().rand()) . $sExt;

        // output image to file
        imagejpeg($vDstImg, $newImageName, $iJpgQuality);
        //@unlink($sTempFileName);

        return $newImageName;
    }

    return false;
}

$sImage = uploadImageFile();
echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
?>
```

Comment: I am new to PHP so it might be a little difficult for me to add argument to a function kindly please provide the details in this http://jsfiddle.net/c8efyejv/

Comment: still it just upload to avatar directory and the rest is empty

Comment: I am not sure, if your solution works as expected, because after calling first time the function, the uploaded image is moved from system's temp folder to the first destination and then (after processing) deleted...

Comment: @BillyG do you have any solution.

Comment: @alex_kalenyuk: This part "move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);" must be executed only once (after that, the image does no more exist in temp) and you have to use the $sTempFileName for the later scaling (this variable is not set on the second call / run)!

Comment: @BillyG do you have any solution.

Comment: If yes then please share

Comment: @BillyG yes you are right. It is better to use several functions for that script, but I need to write some html form for testing. I provide my working code later if no one will do it before

Comment: @alex_kalenyuk Thanks again, but please provide it a little quick as it as an assignment for the university.

Comment: @ARA I've made changes, check it. Tested on local machine

Comment: @alex_kalenyuk thanks, it worked. can i add the latest cropped image URL which is in folder avatar in MySQL database column avatar.

Database server: 127.0.0.1 | Database Name: ara | Database Username: root | Database password:

Comment: @ARA of course you can, but it's another question. Approve this answer, try to implement DB functionality by yourself and if you have any problem, ask new question - I'm sure people will help you

Comment: Hi @alex_kalenyuk please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235738/how-to-save-uploaded-image-names-in-mysql-database) regarding saving uploaded image URL in MySQL database.