# How to save uploaded image names in MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

*Part of this answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187274/save-cropped-image-in-different-width-and-height)*

I have beneath php code which upload one cropped image to 3 different width and height in

1. ***avatar*** directory with width and height 200*200
2. ***avatar1*** directory with width and height 500*500
3. ***avatar2*** directory with width and height 700*700

and renames image with MD5 random.

```
<?php 
    function uploadImageFile() { // Note: GD library is required for this function

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $iJpgQuality = 100;

        if ($_FILES) {
            // if no errors and size less than 250kb
            if (! $_FILES['image_file']['error'] && $_FILES['image_file']['size'] < 250 * 1024) {
                if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'])) {
                    if (!is_dir('avatar')) {
                        mkdir('avatar');
                    }
                    // new unique filename
                    $sTempFileName = 'avatar/' . md5(time().rand());
                    // move uploaded file into cache folder
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $sTempFileName);

                    // change file permission to 644
                    @chmod($sTempFileName, 0644);

                    $sResultFileName = copyImageFile('avatar', $sTempFileName, 200, 200, $iJpgQuality);
                    if ($sResultFileName) {
                        copyImageFile('avatar1', $sTempFileName, 500, 500);
                        copyImageFile('avatar2', $sTempFileName, 700, 700);
                        @unlink($sTempFileName);

                        return $sResultFileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function copyImageFile($dirName, $originImageName, $iWidth, $iHeight, $iJpgQuality = 90) {
    if (file_exists($originImageName) && filesize($originImageName) > 0) {        
        $aSize = getimagesize($originImageName); // try to obtain image info
        if (!$aSize) {
            @unlink($originImageName);
            return;
        }

        // check for image type
        switch($aSize[2]) {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $sExt = '.jpg';
                $vImg = @imagecreatefromjpeg($originImageName);
                break;
            /*case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $sExt = '.gif';

                // create a new image from file 
                $vImg = @imagecreatefromgif($sTempFileName);
                break;*/
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $sExt = '.png';
                $vImg = @imagecreatefrompng($originImageName);
                break;
            default:
                @unlink($originImageName);
                return;
        }

        // create a new true color image
        $vDstImg = @imagecreatetruecolor( $iWidth, $iHeight );

        // copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        imagecopyresampled($vDstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, (int)$_POST['x1'], (int)$_POST['y1'], $iWidth, $iHeight, (int)$_POST['w'], (int)$_POST['h']);

        // define a result image filename        
        if (!is_dir($dirName)) {
            mkdir($dirName);
        }
        $newImageName = $dirName . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(time().rand()) . $sExt;

        // output image to file
        imagejpeg($vDstImg, $newImageName, $iJpgQuality);
        //@unlink($sTempFileName);

        return $newImageName;
    }

    return false;
}

$sImage = uploadImageFile();
echo '<img src="'.$sImage.'" />';
?>
```

**My Question**

I want to save the URL of the 3 recent uploaded image in`ara MySQL`database in

1. `Avatar` column= URL of image which uploaded to avatar directory
2. `Avatar1` column= URL of image which uploaded to avatar1 directory
3. `Avatar2` column= URL of image which uploaded to avatar2 directory

Database name: ara

Database user: root

Database password:

Database address: 127.0.0.1

Table Name: Profiles

Column Names: avatar, avatar1 and avatar2

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269199/php-tot-mysql-image-uploading-not-working/22269447#22269447

Comment: Thanks @Baig, it is good but it is just for one image. please read my question once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
copyImageFile('avatar1', $sTempFileName, 500, 500);
copyImageFile('avatar2', $sTempFileName, 700, 700);
```

replace this code after

```
     include('connect/mysql.php');
    $avatar1=copyImageFile('avatar1', $sTempFileName, 500, 500);
    $avatar2=copyImageFile('avatar2', $sTempFileName, 700, 700);
$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['UserName']);

       mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE profiles SET AvatarImage='".$sResultFileName."',AvatarImageBig='".$avatar1."',AvatarImageSmall='".$avatar2."' WHERE UserName = '$user_name'");   
        mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: can i change the `$con` to `$conn` as i have already used in all other documents.

`<?php

define('DB_HOST', "localhost"); // database location
define('DB_NAME', "ara"); // database name
define('DB_USER', "root"); // user name
define('DB_PASS', ""); // password

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("<div class='msgBox1'>MySQL Error: Oops! UNABLE to CONNECT to the DATABASE!</div>");
mysqli_select_db($conn, DB_NAME) or die("<div class='msgBox1'>MYSQL ERROR</div>");
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8') or die("<div class='msgBox1'>UNABLE to SET database connection</div>");
?>`

Comment: it says ` Undefined variable: conn`

Comment: $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ara") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); change this variable

Comment: where i should change that variable

Comment: i changed it in answer please follow

Comment: I will change to `$con`, but all my database information is in `connect/mysql.php` file and i want to include `mysql.php` file in my pages instead of writing the database connection in every single page.

Comment: when i am adding it it says that 
`Notice: Constant DB_HOST already defined in E:\Easyphp\www\authentication\connect\mysql.php on line 3

Notice: Constant DB_NAME already defined in E:\Easyphp\www\authentication\connect\mysql.php on line 4

Notice: Constant DB_USER already defined in E:\Easyphp\www\authentication\connect\mysql.php on line 5

Notice: Constant DB_PASS already defined in E:\Easyphp\www\authentication\connect\mysql.php on line 6`

and the reason is that i already added require_once(ROOT_PATH.'connect/mysql.php');

but it is not working

Comment: so don't include file here just run your query

Comment: if i don't include it then it says `Notice: Undefined variable: con in E:\Easyphp\www\crop9\upload.php on line 40

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in E:\Easyphp\www\crop9\upload.php on line 40`

Comment: if your mysql.php have $conn variable use that variable

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Banjamin and @Qaisar

> You are using $con in the function
>
> ```
> uploadImageFile($user_name),
> ```
>
> so you should pass the variable `$con` to this function, something
>   like
>
> `uploadImageFile($user_name, $con)` of course then you have to change
>   your functions accepted arguments.